# Python adding empty rows in open with function

Tags: python, pandas, file, csv

I have a few dfs looks like that:

```
A    B    C    D
1    2    3    4
11   22   33   44
111  222  333  444
```

I tried to write they in csv file. I use:

```
with open(matchedLine + 'OUT', 'a') as f:
        df.to_csv(f, header=False, index = False)
```

And in csv i got a empty row after each row. I mean:

```
1 2 3 4

11 22 33 44 

etc
```

Why? How to delete that empty rows? What is wrong with my code?

.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just add the parameter : newline='' in your open function.

The line would be :

```
with open(matchedLine + 'OUT', 'a', newline=''):
```

Comment: Ouh, so simple and I didn't find it :C I though that no \n is default value. Thank u !

Comment: Yeah lines end with \r\n by default, You're welcome

Answer (score 1):

Conformant CSV files have lines ended with `"\r\n"`, whatever the platform to ensure easy sharing. For that reasons in Python 3, the csv library writes the end of lines, and it expects the file to be opened with `newline=''`.

Just write:

```
with open(matchedLine + 'OUT', 'a', newline='') as f:
        df.to_csv(f, header=False, index = False)
```